# PHP parse array to get index wise result

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array like this

```
array:9 [
  "_token" => "A5lA2YRgSS4n7uqcUYHe1NUZVk4Qbg8vTm7hyVLn"
  "date" => array:3 [
    0 => "1982-02-10"
    1 => "2017-07-14"
    2 => "1985-02-14"
    ...
  ]
  "time" => array:3 [
    0 => "09:55"
    1 => "19:22"
    2 => "17:23"
    ...
  ]
  "departure_city" => array:3 [
    0 => "Et aut ullamco non a"
    1 => "Sed beatae eveniet"
    2 => "Autem aut quis nostr"
    ...
  ]
  "departure_state" => array:3 [
    0 => "AK"
    1 => "NY"
    2 => "WY"
    ...
  ]
  "arrival_city" => array:3 [
    0 => "Reprehenderit accus"
    1 => "Adipisicing doloremq"
    2 => "Qui deleniti similiq"
    ...
  ]
  "arrival_state" => array:3 [
    0 => "AR"
    1 => "HI"
    2 => "ND"
    ...
  ]
  "vehicle_type" => array:3 [
    0 => "1"
    1 => "7"
    2 => "2"
    ...
  ]
  "number_of_passengers" => array:3 [
    0 => "3"
    1 => "8"
    2 => "2"
    ...
  ]
]
```

How can I loop over this array and convert it into something like the below array

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:7 [
    date => 1982-02-10,
    time => 09:55,
    departure_city => Et aut ullamco non a,
    departure_satte => AK,
    arrival_city => Reprehenderit accus
    arrival_satate => AR
    vehicle_type => 1,
    number_of_passenger => 3
  ],
  1 => array:7 [
    date => 2017-07-14,
    time => 19:22,
    departure_city => Sed beatae eveniet,
    departure_satte => NY,
    arrival_city => Adipisicing doloremq
    arrival_satate => HI
    vehicle_type => 7,
    number_of_passenger => 8
  ]
...
]
```

Comment: Are you just picking the first item in all the sub-arrays?

Comment: @AlexBarker, yes this would solve the problem

Comment: and the code you have so far is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a foreach, it creates a copy of the array so you can modify within the loop.

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $a[$key] = array_shift($value);
    } else {
        $a[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Update solution based on your updated question. This will only produce an array with 3 elements in it, not 9, but I am *guessing* that is what you want.

```
$b = array();
foreach ($a as $aKey => $aValue) {
    if (is_array($aValue)) {
        foreach ($aValue as $bKey => $bValue) {
            $b[$bKey][$aKey] = $bValue;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($b);
```

Comment: This works only if I need 1 sub-array, from the sample input in my question, I am looking for 3 sub-arrays

Comment: What are you talking about?  I only see 1 sub-array in your sample and I asked if you only wanted the first item to which you confirmed... You need to update your question with more information about exactly what you want.  Are you trying to permeate the results, if so on what conditions?

Comment: @baig772 I have updated the answer with my best guess as to what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You could do something that utilized the relatively unknown `array_column` function:

```
// Cleanup any keys that don't represent record data
unset($x['_token']);
$keys = array_keys($x);
$values = array_values($x);
$merged = [];

$record_cnt = count($x['date']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $record_cnt; $i++) {
  $merged[] = array_combine($keys, array_column($values, $i));
}

print_r($merged);
```